# iOS Multiple Notifications Issue

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

If iOS app receives multiple push notifications, when one of it is opened, all the notifications are opened as new views. Any advice?
This is the code

```
if([category isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    DetailViewController *detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    detailController.newsId = id;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=false;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: follow this , may be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995375/how-to-handle-multiple-push-notifications-with-user-data-arrived-at-different-ti

Comment: another one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716455/how-to-handle-while-multiple-push-notification-comes-at-same-time-in-foreground  and another too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279453/multiple-push-notifications-on-1-device-iphone